# Can't echo wp_count_posts('page')?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to echo the value of the variable in the code below. I'm getting an error (see below)...

Here's the code...

```
$mypagecount = wp_count_posts('page');
echo $mypagecount;
```

Here's the error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wp_count_posts function returns an object.
You can ask the object to return the number of publish items.

```
<?php
     $count_pages = wp_count_posts('page');
     $pages = $count_pages->publish;
     echo $pages;
?>
```

For more information:
http://wpengineer.com/show-amount-of-posts-pages-categories-tags-comments-for-wordpress-themes/